# Сложность операции побитового сдвига

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Сколько стоит проверка бита, стоящего на позиции p числа n ( n >> p ) % 2 = x, где x - искомый бит? Если часто проверять биты одного и того же числа, то ведь лучше их запомнить в памяти, или это не очень существенно?

```
#include <cstdio>
const int maxBit = 16;
int main(){
    int n, i, p;
    scanf("%d", &n );
    char bits[maxBit];
    i = 0;
    while ( n != 0 ){
        bits[i++] = n % 2;
        n /= 2;
    }
    for ( ; i < maxBit; i++ ){
        bits[i] = 0;
    }
    for ( i = maxBit - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
        printf("%d", bits[i] );
    }
    printf("\n");
    // получение бита на позиции p в числе n
    scanf("%d",&p );
    printf("%d", bits[p] );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вам в тактах? Тогда смотрите документацию на процессор.

Comment: @Altruist Покажите, как вы собираетесь их запомнить, и как затем вы собираетесь определять их значения. То есть покажите альтернативный код, эффективность которого вы хотите сравнить с данным кодом. Иначе просто ваш вопрос не имеет никакого смысла, хотя многие поспешили уже отвечать.

Comment: @Altruist "Сколько стоит проверка бита" - Вам в рублях или в долларах расчитать?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Могу в евро. На **продуманную** проверку бита уходит 5 минут времени программиста. Исходя из либеральных фрилансерских расценок в 60 евро/час, получаем 5 евро.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow код написал, мне в асимптотике нужно было, ну в рублях тоже устроило.

Comment: @Altruist Как можно видеть из вашего же кода косвенное обращение к элементам массива, а затем сравнение их значений с 1 или с 0 будет менее эффективно, чем применение одной команды сдвига, которая на многих процессорах сразу же устанавливает флаг результата операции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сложность - O(1).

Это всего две ассемблерных инструкции. А если компилятор нормальный - то вообще одна (BT). Сомневаюсь, что ее можно "ускорить" какими-то оптимизациями.

Answer (score 5):

Вы занимаетесь преждевременной ненужной оптимизацией.

Компилятор гораздо лучше знает, сколько «стоит» выделение бита, и знает, что дороже — закешировать результат проверки или нет. Оставьте нанооптимизации оптимизатору, он сделает это за вас, и скорее всего лучше вас. С хорошей долей вероятности, если смысл вашего кода с запоминанием бит и без одинаков, оптимизирующий компилятор произведёт совершенно одинаковый код.

Даже если бы оптимизаторы были такими, как 20 лет тому назад, и не умели бы оптимизировать битовые операции, всё равно правильно было бы следовать не потенциальному выигрышу в пару наносекунд, а смыслу. Пишите так, как понятнее, и так, чтобы текст программы выражал ваши намерения. Пишите, *что* вы хотите получить, а не *как*.

Потеря одного-двух тактов процессора совершенно не оправдывает ухудшения понимаемости текста. Если вам нужен тотальный контроль — пишите на ассемблере. (Учтите, что современные компиляторы оптимизируют обычно лучше, чем обычный программист напишет на ассемблере вручную.)

Оптимизируйте лучше ваши алгоритмы. Если вы поменяете алгоритм, который бежит за `O(n^2)`, на `O(log n)`, выигрыш будет значительно заметнее.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> ( n >> p ) % 2 = x
> ```

Во-первых, имелось в виду

```
( n >> p ) % 2 == x
```

Во-вторых, лучше делать не так, а

```
(( n >> p ) & 1) == x
```

Потому что если `n` будет отрицательным, то возможными значениями левой части будут `0` и `-1`, следовательно равенство единице никогда не выполнится.

> Если часто проверять биты одного и того же числа, то ведь лучше их запомнить в памяти, или это не очень существенно?

Если очень хочется узнать, то надо запустить и замерить время выполнения соответствующих функций. Естественно, в релизной конфигурации. И обязательно надо использовать как-то результат вычисления, иначе оптимизатор может вообще выкинуть вычисляющий код.

Comment: ( n >> p ) & 1 == x - вот именно так лучше не делать, во первых это не эквивалентно ( n >> p ) % 2 == x в области положительных чисел, во вторых абсолютно не то что требуется

Comment: @outcast, понял. Скобки забыл. Исправил.